# Powershell: Compare-object not comparing nested objects

Tags: json, powershell, comparison

or how I stopped worrying and learned to love the string collection

Given the following two json strings:

```
$jsonString1 = '{ "baz": "quuz", "cow": [ "moo", "CUD" ], "foo": "bar" }'
$jsonstring2 = '{ "baz": "quuz", "cow": [ "moo", "GRASS" ], "foo": "bar" }'
```

I want to get the differences in the objects they represent

```
<# First attempt: Convert each to an object, then compare normally #>
function Compare-Json {
    <# Make powershell objects from each string #>
    $obj1 = $jsonString1 | ConvertFrom-Json
    $obj2 = $jsonstring2 | ConvertFrom-Json

    Compare-Object $obj1 $obj2
}

PS E:\temp> Compare-Json

PS E:\temp>
```

Yes, that is no output at all.

Current workaround is to convert the json into objects, back to strings, then split the strings and finally compare each collection

```
function Compare-Json {
    <# Convert to pretty json, then split to make a string array #>
    $obj1 = $($jsonString1 | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json) -split ([Environment]::NewLine)
    $obj2 = $($jsonstring2 | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json) -split ([Environment]::NewLine)

    Compare-Object $obj1 $obj2
}


PS E:\temp> Compare-Json

InputObject      SideIndicator                                               
-----------      -------------                                               
"GRASS"          =>                                                          
"CUD"            <=                                                          

PS E:\temp>
```

Is there a simpler method to deep-compare two objects?

Comment: Wouldn't your workaround solution fail if properties are out of order within the two JSON strings, but otherwise the objects are identical?  For example, one resolves to
'{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}'
and the other resolves to 
'{"field2":"value2", "field1":"value1"}'
You'd probably want those two to compare as identical, wouldn't you?  But they wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's any better or not, but:

```
$jsonString1 = '{ "baz": "quuz", "cow": [ "moo", "CUD" ], "foo": "bar" }'
$jsonstring2 = '{ "baz": "quuz", "cow": [ "moo", "GRASS" ], "foo": "bar" }'

compare $jsonString1.split(',:[]{}') $jsonString2.split(',:[]{}')


InputObject                                          SideIndicator                                      
-----------                                          -------------                                      
 "GRASS"                                             =>                                                 
 "CUD"                                               <=
```

Comment: None of these solutions are reliable because they depend on the ordering of properties within JSON.  In your example, if the "foo" property were listed first for one of the two objects, and last for the other, then the objects would compare as different even if all values were identical between them.